# Pass parametre from Toggle() action to OnClick() action Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'am using DataTable plugin to visualise all my talbes with an mouse rigth click event!

Div for rigth click

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="margin-right: 3px;"></i>
        Modifier</li>
    <li data-action="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="margin-right: 3px;"></i>Supprimer</li>
</ul>
```

in JS

```
   var table = $('#dataTablesTable').DataTable();
    $('#dataTablesTable tbody').on('contextmenu', 'tr', function (event) {
        if (event.button == 2) {
            var arrString = table.row(this).data();
            var SelectedRow= arrString[0];
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).css({
                top: event.pageY + "px",
                left: event.pageX + "px"
            });
        }


    });

$(".custom-menu li").click(function () {
    ABC = "";
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
        case "Edit": Btn_Edit_Demande_click('EDIT', ABC); break;
        case "Delete": Btn_Delete_Demande_click(ABC); break;
    }
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});
```

how can i pass a parametre from oncontextmenu event (selectedRow) to li click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pass your parametre to global variable, so you can get it later in other function.

Example

```
function setValue()
{
    window.myValue = "test";
}

function getValue()
{
    alert(window.myValue); // "test" (assuming setValue has run)
}
```